# MPU-6050 is not being detected by Raspberry Pi

Tags: i2c, mpu6050

I am trying to interface MPU-6050 with the Raspberry Pi,
Since it require I<sup>2</sup>C connections so I have connected using the following pins:

3.3V connect to VCC
SDA connect to SDA
SCL connect to SCL
Ground connect to GND

However, when I check if the device is detected using `i2cdetect -y 1`, nothing is displayed, just the empty I<sup>2</sup>C address table.

On the other hand, the MPU-6050's yellow light is turned on when it is connected.

I am sure that I have done everything correct because other sensor (BMP085) is being normally displaying in the I<sup>2</sup>C address table when I try to connect to it, additionally an ADC Pi unit is also normally showing in the I<sup>2</sup>C table.

I have tried to connect MPU6050 both with and without the BMP085, but in either case, its address is not displaying in the I<sup>2</sup>C address table.

What could be the problem here?

Beside: VCC, SDA, SCL and GND; am I supposed to connect any other pins too? There are these other pins: XDA, XCL, ADD and INT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some breakouts need a 5V supply and include a 3.3V regulator for the
>   MPU6050 itself. If that's what you have, then you need5V for Vcc.
>
> You will need to set the ADD to either 0v or 3.3V to chooses between
>   the i2c addresses 0x68 or 0x69.
>
> You can leave XDA, XCL and INT unconnected - XDA / XCL provide a
>   master i2c interface for adding (say) a compass, INT provides an
>   interrupt to let the Rpi know when there is fresh sensor data to be
>   read, but you can just poll for the data instead.

Connecting the ADD to 3.3V through a Resistor, and applying 5Volts to the VCC worked for me.
It merits mentioning that you could always check if the device is detected and properly reading the data using these two commands,

```
i2cdetect -y 1
i2cget -y 1
```

Replace '1' by '0' if you have an older version of RPi.